# Raspberry Pi won't connect to VPN

Tags: raspberry-pi, openvpn, nordvpn

I recently installed OpenSSH on my Raspberry Pi and tried to automaticly connect the Pi to a VPN (by NordVPN) on boot. Therefore I downloaded the VPN-files from NordVPN and copied the file to this location:

```
/etc/openvpn/nordvpn.conf
```

In the config file I added this line for auto-connect:

```
auth-user-pass /home/pi/auth.txt
```

I also edited `/var/default/openvpn` and added this line:

```
AUTOSTART=nordvpn
```

But I'm not connected via VPN. This is the output of `sudo systecmtl status openvpn@nordvpn.service`:

```
● openvpn@nordvpn.service - OpenVPN connection to nordvpn
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-04-12 20:15:26 CEST; 681ms 
     Docs: man:openvpn(8)
           https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage
           https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO
  Process: 3276 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-nordvpn --status /run/openvpn/nordvpn.sta Main PID: 3276 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 12 20:15:26 raspberrypi systemd[1]: openvpn@nordvpn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, 
Apr 12 20:15:26 raspberrypi systemd[1]: openvpn@nordvpn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 12 20:15:26 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN connection to nordvpn.
```

Why don't I get access to the VPN?
When running the config file (after renaming it to .ovpn) it works.

Comment: Read the Docs, `man openvpn`, and the two links. In a terminal window, `sudo /usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-nordvpn --status /run/openvpn/nordvpn.sta` to see more messages.

Comment: @waltinator when entering this command (sudo /usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-nordvpn --status /run/openvpn/nordvpn.sta) it don't get any output from the system.

Comment: Try `sudo journalctl  -b 0 /usr/sbin/openvpn`. Or,  `sudo strace /usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-nordvpn --status /run/openvpn/nordvpn.sta` to see a trace of  program execution, way more messages.

Comment: @waltinator It says this:
Apr 13 04:29:01 raspberrypi ovpn-nordvpn[12685]: WARNING: cannot stat file 'auth.conf': No such file or directory (errno=2)
Apr 13 04:29:01 raspberrypi ovpn-nordvpn[12685]: Options error: --auth-user-pass fails with 'auth.conf': No such file or directory (errno=2)

Since the file is there (and openvpn works manuall) can it be that the file can not acces my auth.txt-file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I managed to figure out thanks to the comment of User Waltinator.

The config-file cannot access my auth-file which is located in the home-directory of user pi. I don't know why or how this could be done but moving the auth-file to the openvpn directory solved this problem.